# Overriding bootstrap header border-bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap header, and I don't want it to have a border-bottom. I can't seem to set it to "none" (or white, which is my background).

I have no problems changing the color and size, like so:

```
.navbar {
    border-bottom:4px solid green !important;
}
```

However, when I make it `0px` or `white` or `none` or `transparent`, it reverts to a gray bottom border. How do I get rid of the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gray part you see down below is a CSS shadow which you can overwrite like so:

**CSS**

```
.navbar-inner {
   box-shadow: none;
}
```